# Python search for input in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

When my script is run, it asks for an input. That input is then checked to see if it's in a text file. If it is, text is printed. The code I have below is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
discordname = input("What's your discord name?: ")
file = open('rtf.txt')
for line in file:
    line.strip().split('/n')
    if line.startswith(discordname):

        file.close()
        print("works")
```

Comment: Just use `line.strip()`

Comment: Correct, `split` is converting the string into a list.

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" is not helpful. What does it do, what do you expect? I.e., what is the problem?

Comment: start with what does "not working" mean? What's in your file?

Comment: In general, imagine someone that is not you reading this, and try to see if you've presented enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, check your slashes: `/n` != `\n`

Comment: @Rakesh I fixed it by just having that but it's still not finding my input, its just giving me my else: print("not there")

Comment: Can you post a sample of your text and input?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075502/python3-search-for-input-in-txt-file

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
line.strip().split('\n')
```

is not mutating the information bound to the name `line`, which remains unchanged. Instead it returns a new value. You need to bind that new value to a name in order to use use it. This example might help:

```
In [1]: a = "  v  "

In [2]: a.strip()
Out[2]: 'v'

In [3]: a
Out[3]: '  v  '

In [4]: b = a.strip()

In [5]: a
Out[5]: '  v  '

In [6]: b
Out[6]: 'v'
```

Then `split('\n')` (note that you probably want `\` instead of `/`) further returns a list of substrings split by newlines. Note that this is not very useful because `for line in file:` already splits over lines so the list would have one element at most, and so you should omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, Optimized code is:

```
result =  any(line.startswith(discordname) for line in file.splitlines())
if(result):
    file.close()
    print "works"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make the code more complex. Firstly to open a text file use 'with', because it is more flexible and doesn't need closing. Then, instead of using strip, you can use readlines(). This function converts each line into a list or you can also use method read(), which displays all results as it is.

So,

By using readlines, you can look through the user input in a line as a list, and by using read, you can look through each words. Here is the Solution:

```
discordname = input("What's your discord name? ")
with open('rtf.txt') as file:
       contents = file.readlines()
if discordname in contents:
       print("It exits")
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution:

```
discordname = input("What's your discord name?: ")
with open('rtf.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith(discordname):
            print ("it works")
```

I hope it resolve you're problem.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to get strings as input as well. I suggest this:

```
discordname = raw_input("What's your discord name? ")
with open('rtf.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if discordname in line:
            print "works"
```