# Python3 search for input in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

Basically what I want to achieve is this. I have a text file with only the word test in it. When the script is run it pops up with an input and the user would write test. That input is then checked to see if its in the text file and if it is, it would print works, and if that input isn't in the text file, it would print doesn't work. The code below is not working. When I type test as my input, I just received 9 lines in the terminal each saying doesn't work. As I said, the word test is the only thing in the text file. Any help is appreciated!!

```
discordname = input("What's your discord name?: ")
file = open('rtf.txt')
for line in file:
    line.strip()
    if line.startswith(discordname):

        file.close()
        print("works")
    else:
        print("doesn't work")
```

Comment: Please include 'rtf.txt' here, so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: possibly duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075379/python-search-for-input-in-txt-file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`line.strip()` is not in-place; it returns the stripped line. Try `line = line.strip()`.

Unrelated advice: use a context manager to open / close the file:

```
with open("rtf.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
       ...
# No need to call `file.close()`, it closes automatically here
```

---

This works as expected for me:

find_name.py:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
with open("names.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip().startswith(name):
            print("Found name!")
            break
        else:
            print("Didn't find name!")
```

---

names.txt:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

---

```
$ python3 find_name.py
What's your name? bar
Didn't find name!
Found name!
```

Comment: Still gives the exact same problem :(

Comment: @AngusTimoney Are you sure the text file contains only the word 'test'? And is the input 'test' too?

Comment: yep I've quadruple checked

Comment: @AngusTimoney and now?

Comment: That has worked! Is there anyway to just go straight to the line with the input? instead of printing Didnt find name for each line its not on since this txt file is going to have around 50 lines in it...

Comment: @AngusTimoney Sure, just leave out the `else` clause.

Answer (score -1):

```
discordname = input("What's your discord name? ")
with open('rtf.txt') as file:
    contents = file.readlines()
if discordname in contents:
    print("It exits")
else:
    print("Doesnot exits")
```

Just try this. it works. Or if you want to check on every word try read() instead of readlines()

Comment: I no longer get 9 lines with the else print but It is still only printing "Doesnot exits"

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here. Please provide more information.

Comment: Share you rtf.txt file